# Java exact Date to String conversion (no local GMT offset)

Tags: java, date, utc

I'm trying to do a very simple task.
Convert a time (long myTime) in epoch seconds, to a String (but without any adjustment).

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
Instant AA = Instant.ofEpochSecond(myTime);
String reportDate = df.format(Date.from(AA));
```

The "reportDate" is automatically adjusted with GMT offset of Windows.
I need instead the **exact** instant to string conversion.
I'm new on Java ....

Comment: thanks, I didn't know how to accept answers, ha ha
Your suggestion works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the time zone specifically

```
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

This sets the offset to whatever you need so it will output the same date time on any server.